# Keep SELECT from retrieving rows commited after the start of the transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level

Given this scenario:

```
TIME  TRANSACTION 1             TRANSACTION 2
1sec  BEGIN
2sec  INSERT RECORDS INTO T1   
3sec  (doing other things)      BEGIN
4sec  (doing other things)      (doing other things)   
5sec  COMMIT                    (doing other things)   
6sec                            SELECT * FROM T1    <<- GETS ROWS INSERTED BY T1
```

According to postgres docs:

> Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes during execution of the first SELECT

The question is: how to avoid `SELECT` from getting rows committed between the beginning of transaction and the beginning of query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation you describe is called a "phantom read", and is not possible when you use an isolation level that prevents this like `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html

You can change the isolation level using the `SET TRANSACTION` command:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html

Depending on the interface that you use to connect to the database you might also be able to use the corresponding API calls (e.g. `Connection.setTransactionIsolation()` in Java/JDBC)

Answer (score 1):

Set your transaction isolation level to serializable.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html